# Can a hoop garage withstand items being hung from the frame?

Tags: frame

I have a kayak that takes up lots of floor space in my hoop garage. Will the frame of the garage frame withstand the weight of the kayak if I attach it to the top of the frame (apex) or to the side of the frame on the inside?
I can't find an answer anywhere!

Comment: Single hoop or double hoop truss?  Steel or plastic hoops?  Steel hoops should be able to hold something you can lift by hand.  This is for one kayak only not a bunch of kayaks.  Should spread the weight over two or more hoops.

Comment: How about a picture  showing exactly what you have.

Comment: I've seen hoop garages at the dollar store made from the same plastic tubing that they use for $1 kids hoola hoops.  Those "hoops" can barely support their own weight.   I've seen garages made from rectangular steel trussing.  I've seen ones with positive air pressure.  There are all kinds.  You need to provide more info about the one you have, and you probably need to experiment to see how it behaves. Right now this is a how-long-is-a-string question.

Comment: My guess if it's a residential pop-up one with bendy plastic or fiberglass hoops, it's a bad idea.  With some heavy wind that would normally stress the structure to its limit, the added weight of the kayak might take it beyond.  You need to fortify it with some structure as noted in the one answer so far.  Don't build a hoist because hoisting will put far more stress on it than the static weight of the boat.  You need to gingerly place the boat onto the support that you build, if you do it.

Comment: Youtube has lots of tutorials on how to build a kayak stand from wood 2x4s or 2-inch PVC piping.  Build one inside your hoop garage.  You could easily build a PVC-pipe structure that bridges over your car and is strong enough to support one kayak.  You could build it so it's tied to the hoop structure at the top and bottom, adding strength and weight to the garage making it stronger rather than weaker.

Answer (score 1):

If you hang it from the peak, then the sides will want to bulge out. So use vertical members from the peak to hang the weight, and horizontal members as cross ties to prevent bulging forces. The combination will act as a truss to contain all those forces.